# Factor models with small noises

Tags: factor-analysis, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics

The standard factor model formulation is

$y=W x+\epsilon$

where $x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$, $\epsilon \sim\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$. $W$ and $\Sigma$ are typically estimated from MLE. The solution can be obtained numerically; in general there are no analytical solutions.

Question: assume that $\Sigma$ belongs to some class of psd matrices, such as matrices of bounded norm, or with bounded trace. Is there an analytical solution to factor models in which the noise is vanishing, i.e.

$y=W x+ n^{-1}\epsilon$

with $n\rightarrow \infty$? By this, I mean than the solutions $(W_n, \Sigma_n)$ converge and that possibly the solution can be expressed in closed form. I know the answer is in the affirmative when it is known a priori that $\Sigma = I$, but I would be happy to see that it holds more generally.

Pointers to literature welcome.

Comment: @gappy, there are several articles about the limit theory for factor models, but in [econometrics context](http://www.econ.nyu.edu/user/baij/publication.htm). I dabbled myself in factor models but for me your formulation of the factor model is anything but standard. Could you please provide a reference? As it now stands it is more of regression model than the factor model.

Comment: The factor model I provide *is* the standard definition. Check, say http://learning.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/ul.pdf, and references therein; or Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data by Wooldridge, or Econometrics by Hayashi. I am well aware of Bai and Ng's work, as well as Reichlin et al., and Stock and Watson; but their limit theory has nothing to do with this-- is proves asymptotic convergence of PCA to the factor model for $N$ and $T$ going to infinity.

Comment: @gappy this paper http://www.i-journals.org/ejs/viewarticle.php?id=267&layout=abstract may at least give referencse ?

Comment: @gappy, is that really the convergence statement you're interested in? A variance bound of $O(n^{-2})$ seems pretty strong. Also, what do you mean by "closed form" when you say that for the $\Sigma = I$ case, one gets a "closed form" solution? Thanks.

Comment: @gappy, I reviewed the Wooldridge book and found nothing about factor models, could you please provide page number?

Comment: @gappy Is $n$ also the sample size?  Is $\Sigma$ assumed to be diagonal?  I assume that you are asking for a fixed sample size, what happens to the MLFA solution as the uniquenesses (entries of $\Sigma$, assumed to be diagonal) tend to $0$.  It also sounds like you’ve already seen Tipping and Bishop (1999).

Comment: Let's attempt to re-activate this post: reading the comments it appears that there was some uncertainty about what it was meant by "analytical solution" (to be contrasted to the ML estimation results?), and how it translates to "the solution converge" -which in turn needs some more elaboration. I would also ask, "if the model contains the error by construction, wouldn't a solution in which the error vanishes asymptotically, be the wrong one to obtain?"